# What is the time complexity of adding an element at the beginning of an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Say I have a ArrayList with n element in this array, and I add an element at the beginning:

```
myArrayList.add(0,'some value');
```

What will be the time complexity of this operation?

The [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) doesn't specify this.

Also

I just start learning Java, and I saw the sentence

```
An ArrayList in Java is a List that is backed by an array.
```

What does 'backed' here mean? Thank you!

Comment: It means an `ArrayList` is an implementation, a `List` is an interface.

Comment: An ArrayList is technically just an array in a sense. It uses the System.arraycopy method to handle adding and removing elements. In this case, it will create two arrays, one from 0-0 (empty) and the other from (0-n). It then creates a new array of the length+1 and combines them all together, putting in the new element at the respective index.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Adding an element to beginning of array  is O(n) - it would require to shift all the existing elements by one position.

All elements in an array list are stored in a contiguous array.  If you add more elements than the current size of the array - it will be grown automatically to accommodate the new element.

Addition to the end is O(1) amortized over multiple insertions.

Comment: I know O(n) is the normal case, but I was actually asking if Java does some magic in this case (anything like Louis Wasserman mentioned)? Sorry for not being clear enough!

Comment: What do you mean, "this case"?

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry I mean 'this operation'. this operation usually takes O(n) but I was wondering if Java's implementation has some 'smart way' to add element in beginning of ArrayList. Can you elaborate your answer a little bit why it takes linear time?

Answer (score 13):

`ArrayList.add(0, element)` takes linear time, but the constant is very low, because it can use the blazing fast `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList documentation is indeed obscure on this point -- I looked at it in SE11 just now, and it's unchanged since the first release of the Collections Framework (in Java 1.2).

I believe the intent of the authors of the ArrayList documentation was to specify that, on any implementation of Java, the appending operation (i.e. the `add(E e)` method) must run in constant amortized time, and that the list insertion operation (i.e. the `add(int index, E e)` method) must run in `O(n)` time, where `n` is the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

- Building the list from scratch and adding lots of elements to the beginning runs in quadratic time: O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- Adding all elements to the end of the list and then calling
  [Collections.reverse(list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) runs in linear time: O(n).